# GCM message received but service function is not invoked

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

onMessage is not triggering from the Intent-Service

My Manifest content

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<receiver android:name="com.example.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.example" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name="com.example.GcmIntentService"/>
```

previously it is used to work, now it is not working

GcmIntentService.java

```
public class GcmIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    public GcmIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.info(TAG, "Received GCM message");
    }
}
```

Catlog printed

```
08-07 19:19:36.199: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(6538): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
08-07 19:19:36.199: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(6538): GCM IntentService class: com.example.GcmIntentService
08-07 19:19:36.199: V/GCMBaseIntentService(6538): Acquiring wakelock
08-07 19:19:36.239: V/GCMBaseIntentService(6538): Releasing wakelock
```

Is this something to do with the payload sent?

Comment: Could you post your GcmIntentService class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the official declaration of Google https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid say

> GCM register() is deprecated starting May 28, 2015. New app development should use the Instance ID API to handle the creation, rotation, and updating of registration tokens. For more information, see Registering Client Apps and Implementing GCM Client on Android.

If you still want to use the old methodology then remove the **gcm.jar** forget about **GCMBaseIntentService** and use **WakefulBroadcastReceiver** for your **GcmBroadcastReceiver** and use **IntentService** for your **GcmIntentService**

```
GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(YourActivity.this).register(SENDER_ID)
```

inside an AsyncTask, then it will work.

also you might need the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<permission android:name="[yourpackage].permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="[yourpackage].permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Code for GcmIntentService

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
      protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
          Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
          GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
          String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
          switch (messageType) {
               case GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED:
                    break;
               case GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE:
                    break;
               case GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR:
               default:
                    break;
      }
      GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver code

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public final void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching. 
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a sample code for **GcmIntentService** and **GcmBroadcastReceiver**

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

and implement this class

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.info(TAG, "Received GCM message");
}
```

Comment: this permission already there, are you trying to say GCMBaseIntentService is not working? I have also printed the log for **onReceive** in my question

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add like this

```
<service android:name=".service.GcmService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

then

```
public class GcmService extends GcmListenerService {

    public GcmService() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        ...
     } 
.. 
}
```